# How do I parse a string with GetOpt::Long::GetOptions?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I have a string with possible command line arguments (using an Read-Eval-Print-Loop program) and I want it to be parsed similar to the command line arguments when passed to Getopt::Long.

To elaborate:

I have a string

```
$str = '--infile /tmp/infile_location --outfile /tmp/outfile'
```

I want it to be parsed by GetOptions so that it is easier for me to add new options.

One workaround I could think of is to split the string on whitespace and replace @ARGV with new array and then call GetOptions. something like ...

```
my @arg_arr = split (/\s/, $input_line);

# This is done so that GetOptions reads these new arguments
@ARGV = @arg_arr;
print "ARGV is : @ARGV\n";
GetOptions (
            'infile=s'  => \$infile,
            'outfile=s' => \$outfile
           );
```

Is there any good/better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out the section [parsing options from an arbitrary string](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-string) in the [man page for Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html), I think it does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of splitting on whitespace, use the built-in glob function.  In addition to splitting on whitespace, that will do the standard command line expansions, then return a list.  (For instance * would give a list of files, etc.)  I would also recommend local-izing @ARG on general principle.

<strike>Other than that, that's the only way you can do it without rewriting GetOptions.</strike>  (Clearly I need to read the documentation more carefully.)

Answer (score 5):

Wow!!!

I think I can use both of bentilly and dinomite's answers and do the following:

- use glob to perform standard command line expansions
- pass the array after glob to GetOptionsFromArray method of the GetOpt::Long (see [here](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.37/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#Parsing_options_from_an_arbitrary_array))

Code may look something like ...

```
GetOptionsFromArray ([glob ($input_line)]);
```

And that is only one line .. cool (I know I have to do some error checking etc) .. but its cool ...

Comment: The first argument is an array reference, so you want "GetOptionsFromArray([glob($input_line)],...)"

Answer (score 0):

When you use Getopt::Long on something other than user input, be aware that some features are different based on the POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable.  You can override this with the appropriate call to Configure.

[Obligatory POSIXLY_CORRECT anecdote](http://everything2.com/node/877243).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the methods GetOptionsFromArray and GetOptionsFromString were added only in v2.36 and as Murphy would say I have version 2.35 only.

For now, I think I will have to live with local @ARGV.